# How to test sftp connections to multiple servers with different username and passwords?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a situation where i need to check sftp connectivity to hundred of servers having different username and password combinations. I want to do it using a shell script but i am not sure how to do it with different username and combinations.

I tried using arrays to store different ip,user and password combinations.

```
#!/bin/bash
unix=(10.0.0.1 user1 user@123434)
```

Comment: you can use something like this: https://github.com/net-ssh/net-sftp

Comment: -1 Don't crosspost [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/524207/how-to-test-sftp-connections-to-multiple-servers-with-different-username-and-pas)

Answer (score 0):

Use a brute force tool like `hydra` (https://tools.kali.org/password-attacks/hydra) with a user and password dictionary. If you exactly know all the users and passwords, it should return ACCOUNT FOUND in each case.

In this case, these flags will help you :

```
-L FILE  login with LOGIN name, or load several logins from FILE
-P FILE  try password PASS, or load several passwords from FILE
```

If you get something else than ACCOUNT FOUND, you have a problem on the server.

Comment: Yes, I have list of all usernames and passwords... i will try this.